# Вопрос и ответ в одном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Возможен ли вопрос и ответ в одном предложении?

Например:

Как не участвует? Участвует.

А в одном предложении как это будет выглядеть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Почему не возможен? возможен.*
Вопросительный знак в середине предложения вполне возможен.

> Примечание. Как правило, такое расчленение конструкции в прошлом не влекло за собой употребления прописных букв: Зачем же здесь? и в этот час? (Гр.); Все отвергал: законы! совесть! веру! (Гр.); Чем хуже положение мое, тем язык мой становится связаннее и холоднее. Что мне делать? просить прощения? хорошо, да в чем? (П.). **У некоторых современных авторов еще можно встретить такое оформление подобных конструкций.**
> [Подробнее](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-020.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Возможен: *И какой же русский не любит быстрой езды?*

Для вашего случая: *Как же не участвует, когда он именно участвует?*

Comment: В стиле Бендера : "Как же не выношу, когда я именно выношу!")))

Comment: О! Узнаю брата Васю!

Comment: "Как  не  участвует  -  участвует !"   Можно  и  без  вопросительного  знака  в  середине  предложения.

Answer (score -2):

По моим сведениям, русское предложение может заканчиваться двумя знаками пунктуации  (например, вопросительным и восклицательным знаками). Поэтому я допускаю, что:

1) некоторые русские предложения могут заканчиваться вопросительным знаком и точкой (например, "Вы - русская?."),

2) вышеуказанные русские предложения являются аналогами предложений типа "Вы - русская, не так ли?" ("Are you a Russian, aren't you?").

Comment: Восклицательным  и  вопросительным  может,  а  вопросительным  и  точкой  нет.  Точка  в  этом  случае  избыточна.

Comment: Это, видимо, какие-то секретные сведения. Вопросительный знак и точка указывают на цель высказывания. Предложение не может быть вопросительным и повествовательным одновременно.